# zcat to grep with file name

Tags: unix, grep, zcat

```
ls -ltr|grep 'Mar  4'| awk '{print $9 }'|xargs zcat -fq |grep  12345
```

I'm now using this command to list the records that contain my numeric string how can i alos get this command to print the name of the file the strings were found in?

thanks

Comment: This is not a dup, this is using the answer from 633998 and refining it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [zgrep](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm)

BTW. what you're trying to do can be done with [find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm)

```
find  -newermt 'Mar 4' -and ! -newermt 'Mar 5' -exec zgrep -l '12345' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use **zgrep** instead of zcat+grep (which does the same), you do it like this option like this:

```
ls -ltr | grep 'Mar 4' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs zgrep 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `-t` option to `xargs`, causing it to print the command it is running (the `zcat` command, including the filename) before running it. The command is printed to stderr, so it will not interfere with your pipe.